# How to fetch Edge browsing history programmatically? Is there is any way using COM/Windows API to fetch it?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, com

I am looking how to fetch edge browser browsing history.
I have searched a lot but still not able to find any API/Interface or anyother way through which Edge Browser browsing history can be fetched. 
As we are having interfaces in Win32 which gives us a way to rea Internet explorer browsing history, similarly expecting for edge browser history as well.
Can any one give some idea on this?

Comment: do you mean from a web page? that would be an extreme security hole - why would you need such information?

Comment: No not from webpage. Just wanted to know where edge browsing history data is getting saved in the system or is there any other way? For IE windows api is there to get this information.

Comment: @JaromandaX Why would that be a security hole? I don't think the asker wants to be able to read the history of other users on the system, just the active user.